# How to disable nginx ssl error logging?

Tags: nginx

I've setup SSL configuration on my webserver through the letsencrypt system.

However it seems that some clients are trying to connect that either have too old versions of SSL, or are deliberately trying to use versions that Letsencrypt won't allow, so I get errors like this in the Nginx log:

```
2019/08/25 00:51:03 [crit] 30332#30332: *59285 SSL_do_handshake() failed 
(SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version
too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 1.2.3.4, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

I'm never going to do anything about these events, so I don't need that info to be logged, and they get in the way of viewing actual errors.

Is there any way of telling nginx to not log these types of errors?

Comment: check your ssl settings, even the nginx.conf can hold some information, but since you hide your config from us, my glasball is telling me there is something set

Comment: access_log /dev/stdout;
error_log /dev/stderr;

That's the standard error logging.

Answer (score 0):

```
error_log error.log error;
http {
    server {
        error_log error.log alert;
    }
}
```

If it didn't help, then:

```
error_log error.log error;
http {
    error_log error.log alert;
    server {
        error_log error.log error;
    }
}
```

If it didn't help, then:

```
error_log error.log alert;
http {
    error_log error.log error;
    server {
    }
}
```

Source: https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log

Comment: Turning off all logging of crit and below levels would technically work, but also disable logging of actually imporant stuff...

Comment: @Danack There is no other way. You can write a script to filter the log before viewing it.